# Views integration - Missing handler for custom fields on relationships broken since upgrade to 4.7.15

Tags: drupal-views

I have a report in views that pulls data from custom fields on a relationship between two contacts.

Since an upgrade to 4.7.15 It is no longer displaying that data and on opening the view I see that the fields have the notice "missing handler"

I've cleared caches and ensured that the Drupal database is fully updated and so on.

Could this may be another symptom of: CRM-19545. PR-417

Can anyone shed light or suggests steps to resolve?

Comment: What did you upgrade from? The way we handle Relationships in Views was changed quite a long time ago. But without knowing your previous version it may not be relevant

Comment: also i see that jira issues says Fixed for 4.7.17 so upgrading to that seems to make sense if only to rule out that as being an issue.

Comment: @petednz - fuzion - Thanks for your comments  - Upgraded from 4.7.10  (for a charity I used to work with that has not had any maintenance for some time) - I have also seen that the fix has been committed to the 4.7.17 release but presumably 17 will be released after 16 which has not yet been released... I have been unable to find the patch to apply as an interim measure.

Comment: I've manually applied the changes given in the commit - all working.

Comment: I am having the same issue, i upgraded from CiviCRM 4.7.27 to 5.3.0. Its failing for not only custom fields but CiviCRM events fields also like title, start_date, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Just ran into the issue when upgrading from 4.7.13 to 4.7.16. Spent way too much time trying to figure it out and far too many views data cache clears/drush cc all.

In case anyone runs across this having the same problem, this is a direct link to the revert patch mentioned above: [CRM-19545: Revert CRM-18776 to get back missing custom fields](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-drupal/pull/417/commits/b40430781786aa2102a2fa0aa289c1f55a64911d)